# React useMediaQuery hook dont work on iphones

Tags: reactjs, mobile, media-queries

I am working on this site with useMediaQuery to render different content on mobile and desktop. On Android, everything works great, however it looks like on iPhones, this hook is not working properly.

Do you guys have any idea for a solution?

Link to my website: http://beedevelopment.pl

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: it is supposed to look like this -> https://imgur.com/a/Aszn00O. Seprate sections with navigation using swipes. As i said on chrome it works fine but on iphones it is just smaller version of desktop render.